# Android Library project can't import R class of another library project when using gradle to compile on command line

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle, r.java-file, build.gradle

I have this structure for my android project:

```
ProjectDir  
settings.gradle  
MyApp(depends on LibraryA and LibraryB)  
-->build.gradle  
-->All the other android code  
LibraryA  (depends on LibraryB)  
-->build.gradle  
-->All the other android code  
LibraryB (Has lots of resources that are used in LibraryA and MyApp)  
-->build.gradle  
-->All the other android code
```

I can compile the android app just fine using both eclipse and Android Studio.  LibraryA imports the R file of LibraryB by doing "    `import com.LibraryB.R;`" I also make use of `com.LibraryB.R.layout....` type references in code and as long as I'm in the IDE things are fine.

I am trying to get things to build from the command line for our CI server and I have tried both ant and gradle and I end up getting the same build error in each.

```
LibraryA/example.java:10:error:cannot find symbol import com.LibraryB.R
```

I have even gone to the extent of publishing LibraryB as a local aar file and using it to build LibraryA

LibraryB build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}

group = 'com.libraryb'
version = '1.0'

apply plugin: 'android-library'
apply plugin: 'maven'

uploadArchives {
        repositories {
                mavenDeployer {
                        repository url: 'file://' + new File(System.getProperty('user.home'), '.m2/repository').absolutePath
                }
        }
}

task install(dependsOn: uploadArchives)

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "18.0.1"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }
}
```

LibraryA build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android-library'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile 'com.libraryb:LibraryB:1.0'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "18.0.1"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
}
```

MyApp build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}

group = 'com.myapp'
version = '1.0'

apply plugin: 'android-library'
apply plugin: 'maven'

uploadArchives {
        repositories {
                mavenDeployer {
                        repository url: 'file://' + new File(System.getProperty('user.home'), '.m2/repository').absolutePath
                }
        }
}

task install(dependsOn: uploadArchives)

repositories {
mavenLocal()
mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':LibraryA')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "18.0.1"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
}
```

settings.gradle

```
include ':MyApp'
include ':LibraryA'
```

I need to be able to access the resources of LibraryB from other library projects and the main app.  I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.  Any help would be great.  Fyi, using the generated gradle scripts from eclipse give the same issue.

Comment: I have the same issue, as I tried to reuse some custom UI elements in a library project. Did you discover what is causing that issue?

Answer (score 7):

Hello I had same problem, my android library project, uses another library (actionBarSherlock). It can't resolve import com.actionbarsherlock.R; 
when I changed the line in gradle.build:
 apply plugin: 'android-library' 
to:
 apply plugin: 'android' 
then it goes well.

But I needed it have like a library.

SOLUTION HERE:
Solution Is that R files from included library are generated to your library.
instead import com.actionbarsherlock.R;
use import com.myprojectalsolibrary.R;

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried including

```
include ':LibraryB'
```

in your settings.gradle?