# Gradle Build Order

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, build-process, libraries

I have a project using the android libraries.

Library A depends on Library C.

When build task starts it always fail in `compileDebugJava`,because Library A need resources of Library C.

error: package com.mypackage.libraryC.R does not exist

Gradle runs build tasks with alphabet order.

How to change build order in that situtation?

I need to first build all tasks for Library C and then start building Library A(library A should see library C R.class.

Thanks.

gradle error stack trace:

```
:liraryC:processReleaseJavaRes
:libraryC:packageReleaseJar
:libraryC:compileReleaseNdk
:libraryC:packageReleaseJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:libraryC:packageReleaseLocalJar
:libraryC:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:libraryC:bundleRelease
:libraryC:prepareLibrary
:libraryA:prepareDebugDependencies
:libraryA:compileDebugAidl
:libraryA:compileDebugRenderscript
:libraryA:generateDebugBuildConfig
:libraryA:mergeDebugAssets
:libraryA:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:libraryA:generateDebugResources
:libraryA:mergeDebugResources
:libraryA:processDebugManifest
:libraryA:processDebugResources
:libraryA:generateDebugSources
libraryA:compileDebugJava

 error: package com.mypackage.libraryC.R does not exist
```

Library A build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
  compile project(':LibraryC')
}
```

Library C build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
// other dependencies
}
```

Comment: please post your `.gradle` files for library A and C

Comment: see question updates

Comment: where/how do you use `com.mypackage.libraryC.R` class in your library A source codes?

Comment: I use resources from library C in library A code

Comment: try rebuild you project and tell what happens (= clean & build)

Comment: This article helps to solve my issue
:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18646157/android-library-project-cant-import-r-class-of-another-library-project-when-usi#comment28806646_18646157

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since I used gradle but if I am remembered correctly,if the dependencies are correctly expressed in the gradle files, it should build in the correct order.

You should put a dependency for C in the gradle file of library A.

Comment: I do it,but it fails.                                        dependencies { compile project(':libraryC') }  // build.gradle of library A

Comment: Sounds good to me, you probably have a syntax error or something like this.

See this project as an example of what you are trying to do https://github.com/minsko/gradleMultiLibrary